# Hide labels on x-axis ChartJS

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js

I want to hide labels on x-axis as i have a solution to set

`$scope.labels = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];`

but in that case labels are also getting hidden on tooltip. What i want is to show labels on bars hover but i don't want to show those labels on x-axis. As it also disturbs my UX as well because charts width is too low.

I did spend too much time on this but couldn't find a solution to get rid of x-axis labels. Please help me here....

Answer (score 9):

I think that's something you can do it with options setting in the latest versions of chartjs:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                }
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the simplest fix which actually worked. Unfortunately I missed it while the complicated ones caught my eyes. Hence wasted few hours.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the chart to do this, like so

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: "BarAlt",
    initialize: function(data){
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        var xLabels = this.scale.xLabels;
        for (var i = 0; i < xLabels.length; i++)
            xLabels[i] = '';
    }
});
```

and call it like so

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).BarAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kq3utvnu/

---

Thanks @Samuele for pointing this out! For really long labels, you'll need to set the labels to something shorter and then set it back to the original ones (in the chart elements) so that no space is taken up below the x axis for the labels.

```
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: "BarAlt",
    initialize: function(data){
        var originalLabels = data.labels;
        data.labels = data.labels.map(function() { return '' });

        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.datasets[0].bars.forEach(function(bar, i) {
            bar.label = originalLabels[i];
        });
        var xLabels = this.scale.xLabels;
        for (var i = 0; i < xLabels.length; i++)
        xLabels[i] = '';
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nkbevuoe/

Comment: This solution has a problem. It's just hiding the labels...  So if you have long labels, the chart will not fit correctly.  Example: labels: ["Januaryblablablablablablablablablabla", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],

Comment: @Samuele - You can work around that by setting the labels before you initialize and then setting them back after the initialization. I've updated the answer. Cheers and Thanks!

Comment: You no longer need this workaround - @marcin-wasilewski's answer works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hide labels on the x-axis, while keeping the title in the tooltip by doing the following:

- In chart data: `labels: [""]`
- In chart options, add `object.label = "ToolTipTitle";` before the line specifying the values that should be returned

Comment: Could you please show your `options` object so I can see exactly what you mean?

Comment: I can not imagine how this would work. How will the chart know the values for x-axis for every data point if you set `labels: [""]` in the chart data.