# how to hide tick labels on chartjs/vue-chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying hide the labels along the axis in the following Radial chart:

[image: Radial chart with labels along axis]

This is part of a VueJS application using `vue-chartjs` (which as of time of writing doesn't support version 3 of `chart.js` and therefore the latest documentation is not applicable)

Versions:

```
"vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1"
"chart.js": "^2.9.4"
```

I have tried variations offered in the following thread with no joy (but they are mostly for latest version of `chart.js`: [Hide labels on x-axis ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841302/hide-labels-on-x-axis-chartjs)

This makes it disappear but the other labels (Mean Error, Loss Loss etc) also disappear:

```
scale: {
      display: false
    }
```

[Point Labels](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/axes/radial/linear.html#point-label-options) looked promising from documentation, but doesn't seem to have an effect (maybe I've missed a nesting):

```
pointLabels: { //should this be nested in another parent in the config?
      display: false
    }
```

What is the correct configuration to just make the numbers along the tick marks disappear only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put the display false in the `tick` sub config in the `scale` config like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {

      ticks: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```